# how to truncate decimal places in databricks without rounding off in databricks?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

`select truncate(12.455555,2)`

I was trying to truncate the decimal value in the database from databricks but it was giving me the following error. it gave the same error when I tried executing a simple statement for trimming the decimal places given above.

Error-

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'truncate'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7

Can anyone tell me how we can truncate the decimal places without rounding off the decimals?

Comment: I don't know databicks, but I googled and found no `truncate(num1, num2)` function for it, so how have you come up with that? What I have found is `FLOOR` here: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/floor.html. Hence my take on this would be: `select floor(12.455555 * 100) / 100`.

Comment: well that's my question. How we can trim off the decimal places without rounding off the values. For sql we can use truncate but when I tried doing the same in databricks it is giving me error

Comment: I know `TRUNCATE` only for truncating tables in SQL, but well, this may depend on the DBMS. I hope the `FLOOR` solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring`.

```
spark.sql("select substring(12.455555,0, instr(12.455555,'.')+2) as out").show()

+-----+
|  out|
+-----+
|12.45|
+-----+
```

Comment: this will round off the value, I just want to trim the decimal values to a certain number. I had tried this

Comment: spark.sql("select split('12.456789','[.]')[3] as output").show() this returned null

Comment: Sorry I though you don't want numbers after `.`. Check now.